# Enumerating cohesive clusters over graphs

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Imagine that you are given a graph and X marbles.

You are then asked to place the marbles on the nodes of the graph, in a way that all marbles are placed in a node adjacent to any other node with a marble.

Is it possible to analytically enumerate the number of all different possible arrangements?

Comment: I'm not sure what "all marebles are placed in a dode adjacent to any other node with a marble" means. Could you please state that more precisely?

Comment: I am sorry if the initial statement is not clear. Let me rephrase.

Arrange the marbles in such a way that you can "walk across" all the marble-d nodes without touching an empty node.

Comment: It seems you want the number of [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Connected_graph) [(vertex-)induced subgraphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-InducedSubgraph.html) of order $X$ in a given graph $G,$ is that right? (Not anything I would have guessed from your statement "all marbles are placed in a node adjacent to any other node with a marble.) Now, can you explain what you mean by "analytically", given that the input is a graph? The graph is represented how, as an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)?

Comment: I can see that my initial question was not as firmly put as I thought it was. Yes, I am looking for the number of connected vertex-induced subgraphs.
Furthermore, I need to rephrase the "you are given a graph". I meant that you are given an adjacency matrix. It would be even better if you could make arguments given just a degree distribution.